# Telegram webhook дублирует сообщения

Tags: python, flask

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: делаю бота на Flask в Telegram впервые, на Heroku. Долго промучался с установкой webHook'a, вроде получилось, но теперь сообщения дублируются. Выглядит это так: [image: пишу сообщение, а ответ дублируется]

Вот код:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import telebot
import os

server = Flask(__name__)
TOKEN  = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) #тут мой токен
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))

@server.route('/')
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url="https://myapp/bot") #ссылку изменил
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_messages(
        [telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8")).message])
    return "!", 200

@bot.message_handler()
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hi') #вот эта часть кода исполняется два или три раза

server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Файл Procfile:

```
web: python app.py
```

Спасибо за помощь, сам в замешательстве, сижу уже битый час над этим.

Comment: Удалось решить проблемы? У меня более жирная =) Я деплою банально Ваш скрипт - и бот молчит ... По логам получаю следующее: http://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Kd6.png

Comment: В моем случае помогло установка последней версии pytelegrambotapi

Comment: А какой была версия до того и какую вы установили? Вопросу уже 1,5 года.

Comment: С какой на какую?

Answer (score 1):

Замени

```
@server.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_messages(
        [telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8")).message])
    return "!", 200
```

на

```
@server.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_messages(
        [telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8")).message])
    return "ok", 200
```